# Test missed in selenium using python

Tags: python, selenium, python-unittest

I am trying to test the website [live.guru99.com](http://live.guru99.com). I am testing three functionalities, named tests A, B and C. I am testing the code using geckodriver, whose exe is in the root folder.

The code is as follows:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
import unittest

class Guru99BankTest(unittest.TestCase):

    @classmethod
    def setUp(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()

    def test_C(self):
        driver = self.driver
        driver.get("http://live.guru99.com/")

        driver.find_element_by_link_text('Mobile').click()

        listed_prd_el = driver.find_element_by_xpath(
            "//a[contains(text(), 'Sony Xperia')]/ancestor::div[@class = 'product-info']")
        listed_prd_el.find_element_by_tag_name('button').click()

        qty = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@title='Qty']")

        qty.clear()
        qty.send_keys('1000')

        self.assertEqual(qty.get_attribute('value'), '1000')

        driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@title='Update']").click()

        time.sleep(3)
        self.assertIn('products cannot be ordered in requested quantity',
                      driver.find_element_by_class_name('error-msg').text)

        driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@title='Empty Cart']").click()

        time.sleep(3)

        self.assertIn('no items in your shopping cart',
                      driver.find_element_by_class_name('cart-empty').text)

    def test_A(self):
        driver = self.driver

        driver.get("http://live.guru99.com/")

        self.assertIn("This is demo site for", driver.page_source)

        driver.find_element_by_link_text('Mobile').click()

        self.assertEqual("Mobile", driver.title)

    def test_B(self):
        driver = self.driver

        driver.get("http://live.guru99.com/")

        driver.find_element_by_link_text('Mobile').click()

        driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@title='Sort By']/option[contains(text(), 'Name')]").click()

        product_names = ([e.text for e in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//h2[@class='product-name']")])

        self.assertEqual(product_names, sorted(product_names))

        listed_prd_el = driver.find_element_by_xpath(
            "//a[contains(text(), 'Sony Xperia')]/ancestor::div[@class = 'product-info']")
        listed_price = listed_prd_el.find_element_by_class_name("price").text

        listed_prd_el.find_element_by_tag_name('a').click()

        prod_price = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[@class="price"]').text

        self.assertEqual(listed_price, prod_price)



    @classmethod
    def tearDown(self):
        self.driver.close()

def custom_suite():
    suite = unittest.TestSuite()
    suite.addTest(Guru99BankTest('test_A'))
    suite.addTest(Guru99BankTest('test_B'))
    suite.addTest(Guru99BankTest('test_C'))
    return suite

if __name__ == "__main__":
    runner = unittest.TextTestRunner()
    runner.run(custom_suite())
```

However, I find that the browser opens only one time and not three times.What am I doing wrong? I am quite new at unittests, so please bear with me.

Comment: there are two tests with the same name test_B, is it intentional?

Comment: @michaelsatish I am sorry that was a typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It worked for me. I changed the last test to test_C as test_b was duplicated. However, having said that I'm not sure if that's the actual situation

Comment: I just get a ran 1 test in my console

Comment: Try running it in chrome, not sure it that will make any difference, I'd the chrome driver lying aroung, so fired your code in Chrome and worked. But I dont think browser type and instance determines the flow